# Worklight 6.2 - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

In Worklight 6.2, there is new method to deploy the Worklight Project, which is using IBM Worklight Server Configuration Tool
refer here :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html

After setup Worklight admin, and deploy Worklight Project WAR through that. From my understanding, the worklight project will be called runtime
I found errors on the Websphere Logs as below:

```
[10/3/14 0:37:55:758 MYT] 0000007e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /apps/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_6adbbbb2_14.10.03_00.37.55.7436943857084851194341.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters -RE 1123
[10/3/14 0:37:55:758 MYT] 0000007e LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[10/3/14 0:37:55:769 MYT] 0000007e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[ServletNameNotFound]: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in the `http://localhost:9080/worklightconsole/index.html#`
Got display as below:

Below is the proof that runtime/worklight project is deployed successfully:

[image]

​Next action is to troubleshoot why the runtime/Worklight project is not working.

[image]

How I can rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is in a web container class of WebSphere. You must look at the content of the ffdc file 
/apps/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/server1_6adbbbb2_14.10.03_00.37.55.7436943857084851194341.txt to see if there are more details in particular the servlet that cannot be found.

But it seems that something is wrong in the Worklight configuration under WAS (viewing the "Servlet not found" error).

The Worklight servlets are in the jar "worklight-jee-library.jar" that is configured as a shared library in WAS. 
Without all the WAS logs it is not possible to find the real cause. So you can review the WAS configuration after the deployment by following :

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_wladmin_manually.html,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_oracle_manually_for_wladmin.html,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_oracle_manually.html,

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_manually.html

The other reason could be that your Worklight project is not a 6.2 project. How do you build you war file ?